# replace 2 strings at a time in velocity template

Tags: java, velocity, apache-velocity

SERIAL_NUMBER {SerialNumber} not found in iLPN/Tote {IlpnId}

I want to replace {SerialNumber} with some value and also want to replace {abcd} with some value at a time.
I am able to replace either {SerialNumber} or {abcd} one at a time but not both.

how to do this using velocity template language?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can replace multiple variables in a string using Velocity Template Language:

```
#set($SerialNumber = "1234")
#set($abcd = "xyz")
SERIAL_NUMBER $SerialNumber not found in iLPN/Tote $abcd
```

In the above example, `$SerialNumber` and `$abcd` are two variables that are being replaced with the values `"1234"` and `"xyz"` respectively.